# Changing class variable value from an activity

Tags: android

I have a class which is named `DataView`, it is called from my `Mainactivity` and it draws a radar on the screen. The radar has parameters (radius, ...) that I want to be able to be changed from my `ParametersActivity`.

I'd like to know what's the correct way to set those parameters in the `DataView` so the changes on the radar are taken into account.

Should I use the `SharedPreferences`?

Comment: can you post the code of your activity and dataview class please?

Comment: is the ParametersActivity simply settings that you use?

Comment: The ParametersActivity is basically a layout with a seekbar to change my radius

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case `sharedPreferences` is fine to use. It's good for settings that you want to remember etc, that's what it's for.

If you want it to restore to default on every restart of the app, maybe it would be better to just go to your `ParametersActivity` with `startActivityForResult` and return back the new radius.